# OSX Sierra Elasticsearch -- Not Starting

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, homebrew

I used `brew` to install Elasticsearch and configured via:

http://www.adrianlabastida.com/blog/?p=128#respond

ElasticSearch starts but I can't access localhost:9200 and there isn't any logs I can find for triaging.

Anyone can point me to where the logs could exist on where to track this down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better download Elasticsearch manually with the flowing steps:

1. Get the install package https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch ,eg:elasticsearch-5.4.0.tar.gz
2. Unzip it:`tar -zxvf elasticsearch-5.4.0.tar.gz`
3. Go to the Elasticsearch folder:`yourpath:/elasticsearch-5.4.0`
4. Start it : `./bin/elasticsearch`
5. visit 9200 port:http://localhost:9200/

Answer (score 0):

```
brew info elasticsearch
```

The above will show paths to the relevant log files